# How to show loader when form loading?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have a PHP page. The waiting time to submit the form and get response is different each time. It depends on number data I submit.

How can I show loader when this form is submitting and stop after it done?

PS: I found a nice CSS loader: https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders.

Comment: Are you using ajax() for data submitting?

Comment: are you using ajax?

Comment: no, I not use ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function($){
  $(function(){
      $('#form').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var loading_image = $('#form_loading_img'),
            data = $(this).serialize(),
            form = $(this);
            loading_image.show();
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                type: form.attr('method'),
                data: data,
                success:function(){
                     window.location.reload();
                },
                error:function(){
                  alert('Something goes wrong. Please check the form and try again.');
                },
                complete:function(){
                   loading_image.hide();
                }
            });
      });
  });
})(jQuery);
<img src="http://www.mytreedb.com/uploads/mytreedb/loader/ajax_loader_gray_512.gif" id="form_loading_img" style="display:none">
<form action="action.php" id="form" method="post">
     <!--- Your form element ---->
</form>
```

Comment: its ajax call I think you need non ajax

Comment: It is not possible to show a image or message during form upload with only PHP. Best and simple solution in ajax. JQuery Ajax is simple then JavaScript. If I am wrong please suggest me a another method it will helpfull to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax then you can start showing GIF on click of a button and then in done event of ajax call you can remove the loading GIF

Initially use this

```
<div id="showGif" style="display:none"><img src="~/loding.gif"></div>
```

And in on click of submit use

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
     $("#showGif").attr("style","");

})
```

and in success function of your ajax call use

```
$("#showGif").attr("style","display:none");
```

But if you are using complete Post then your Gif won't be displayed for extire request and response.

If still need it you need to show on submit button's click event as shown above. But initially you need to keep the display property to none of containing GIF `div`,

Comment: how about that +?

Comment: uhh..don't use `.attr('style'...` - just use `.hide()` and `.show()` instead. It's shorter, clearer, and you're not clearing out any inline styles that may be there.